# Get the first data that does not occur twice

Tags: php, laravel

How can I write a query that will get the first active game_id that does not occur twice in the table below?

[image]

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: what i tried was to get all the active game_id first, loop through them return the first game_id that does not occur twice...but i'm thinking a single query can do this..that why i posted this

Comment: Try to create the SQL query first. You probably need a `GROUP BY game_id HAVING count(game_id) > 1` to group them by `game_id`, but only where it's been duplicated, and an `ORDER BY` clause to get the "first" (that's an arbitrary word though, first by `id`? first by occurence? etc.)

Comment: okay...will try this

Comment: Woops, I read this wrong; the `HAVING` clause would be `= 1`, not `> 1`; I thought you were looking for the first that _was_ duplicated. Same approach, different logic 

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
DB::table('tablename')
    ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(game_id) as totalgames, game_id'))
    ->where('is_active', 1)
    ->groupBy('game_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(game_id) = 1')
    ->first();
```

Comment: DB::table("game_user")
                ->select('game_id', DB::raw("COUNT(*) as total"))
                ->where('is_active', true)
                ->groupBy("game_id")
                ->havingRaw("COUNT(game_id) = 1")
                ->first();
The above query works perfectly

Comment: I only using my phone so It's kinda mess.

Comment: @xenooooo Ah, totally understandable! I don't even wanna imagine having to write code on my phone; you're a braver person than I am. Kudos for the great answer too; cheers! 

Answer (score 0):

This will only show all the game id and the number of their occurences

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
                 ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('browser')
                 ->get();
```